# Visual studio community, cordova app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap

I would like to ask If I develop an Apache Cordova app in Visual studio community, do I need to pay to visual studio for publishing the app?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to pay apart from standard VS licencing - to quote from

[Microsoft's web page](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/)

> An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.
>   For all other usage scenarios:
>   In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if I can use intelij comminity instead? if not, is there any other editor/studio that you recommend me for devoloping such application?

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. I'm a one man company yet to release my app, so VS community is fine for me